# Replace HTML Element Contents

Tags: php, html

I have the following HTML.

```
<div class="red">Div One</div>
<div class="green">Div Two</div>
<div class="blue">Div Three</div>
```

What's the best way of replacing the text in the div with the green class?

Also, I need a way of retrieving the contents of a tag by element name (), or element name and class ().

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this an input file you're reading, or part of the webpage you're generating with PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use some kind of HTML parser. I'd use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/).

In the edge case, you can use regex. But I do not recommend this to you!

```
$html = preg_replace('~(<div class="green">)(.*)(</div>)~', '$1Replacement$2', $html);
```

if you want to use class green optional, use

```
$html = preg_replace('~(<div( class="green">|>))(.*)(</div>)~', '$1Replacement$4', $html);
```

Comment: There are cases where regular expressions is bad, and yes, HTML is not a regular language, but sometimes it's still often preferable to use regex for something as simple as this, instead of loading a heavy XML library.

Comment: @Martin what is so bad about using regex for parsing HTML?

Comment: @Martin How do I edit the regex so that either <div class="green" or <div> is present?

Comment: @user826855: imagine that you'll accidentally add a space after `class="green"`. Everything breaks. That won't happen in HTML parsers.

Comment: @user826855: you want to create class green optional?

Comment: @Martin isn't that good if everything breaks? Atleast you know there is a problem then.

Comment: @Martin that's correct. The green class should be optional How can this be done?

Comment: The first one should have `$1Replacement$3` not `$1Replacement$2` (to match the closing `div`)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery can do it for you

```
$(".green").empty().html("your new content for div");
```

and to retrieve content

```
var content=$(".blue").html();  //retrieves content inside class blue
```

Comment: why would you use `.empty` when `.html` replaces the current content with the new itself?

Comment: Quentin Its a jQuery

@nav_nav .empty is not necessary here but I just wrote it to make clear understanding even while reading only.